# Firebase Android how to save data without updating all the children

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a step counter app and I'm trying to save daily steps. The issue I'm having is that when I save the steps for a certain day it'll update all the days in the database with the steps for the current day.

Steps.kt

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
    var currentDate = sdf.format(Date())

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {

        //check if date has changed
        isDateChanged()
}

private fun isDateChanged() {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
        val dateComparison = sdf.format(Date())

        val user = auth.currentUser
        val userreference = databaseReference?.child(user?.uid!!)

        userreference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(currentDate == dateComparison){
                    return
                }else{
                    currentDate = dateComparison;
                    userreference.child("step_data").child("$currentDate").setValue(currentStepsInt) //save steps to firebase
```

In the snippet of code above what is happening is the code is checking if the date has changed. If it has changed, then it'll save the current steps (currentStepsInt) to the database.

In the picture below I get this problem. So for example if at the end of the day of 21-03-2021 the count is 120, it'll save at 120. Then if at the end of 22-03-2021 the count is 190, it'll update all the entries under "steps_data" in firebase as 190. How do I make it so that it'll only update the value for the corresponding day only?

[image]

Above is a picture of how the data looks in the Firebase database.

I would appreciate if anyone can help with this issue.

Edit: The isDateChanged() is called when the sensor detects a change.

Edit 2: I suspect the issue is because of the "child("$currentDate").setValue(currentStepsInt)" part of the code, so Firebase is overwriting each entry that is $currentDate.

How would I get around this issue?

Comment: Code looks fine for me. Post the code where you call the ```isDateChanged()``` function.

Comment: I've updated the post to show where isDateChanged() is called

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
`userreference.child("step_data/$currentDate").setValue(currentStepsInt)`

Comment: Yes I've tried this and still gives the same result

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Realtime database in a long time, for Firestore that's how you would do it. If trying my updated answer does not work, I recommend reading this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields